# How to post on friend wall using Graph Api in iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

i am implementing a facebook application , i have used Graph Api and have successfully logged into facebook and got the friend list with the id in UITableView, now i have one string, how should i post on friend wall, Suppose if i click on any of my friend in UITableView, a message should be post,plz help me

EDIT: Code

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"graph.facebook.com/%@/feed",key];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
ASIFormDataRequest *newRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[newRequest setPostValue:@"I'm inviting you to see download the OGC app" forKey:@"message"];
[newRequest setPostValue:fbGraph forKey:@"access_token"];
[newRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(postToWallFinished:)];
[newRequest setDelegate:self];
[newRequest startAsynchronous];
```

i am implementing this in function when clicked on tableview where key is id number for the friends name clicked in and in other function

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];
NSString *postId = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"id"];
NSLog(@"Post id is: %@", postId);
```

but i am getting the post id nil plz help me

Comment: in uitableview i have tried to call function for post feed but didn't help

Comment: What is the output of the raw responseString from the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the [Facebook iOS SDK?](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/)

Assuming you are, use `requestWithGraphPath` e.g.-

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"uid/feed"
                                andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Post on wall" forKey:@"message"]
                                andHTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                andDelegate:self];
```

Where `uid` is the user id of the user, naturally.

You'll need to make sure you have the relevant permissions when signing in to Facebook and handle the delegate call back to test for success.

If you're not using the SDK, you can do a similar thing with the Graph API directly, perhaps using your own NSURLConnection's or a third party library like ASIHTTPRequest. The SDK is pretty good and straightforward to use mind.

Comment: NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/feed",key];
    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    
    ASIFormDataRequest *newRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [newRequest setPostValue:@"I'm inviting you to see download the OGC app" forKey:@"message"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:fbGraph forKey:@"access_token"];
    [newRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(postToWallFinished:)];
    
    [newRequest setDelegate:self];
    [newRequest startAsynchronous];
i am implementing this in function when clicked on tableview

Comment: where key is id number for the friends name clicked in and in other function     NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    
    NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];
   
    NSString *postId = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"id"];
   
    NSLog(@"Post id is: %@", postId);
but i am getting the post id nil plz help me

Comment: I think you meant that code to go with your question. I'll move it there.